# Why does this not create a date?

Tags: java

I'm passing in a string like "2012-02-20'T'01:01:01"

```
 /**
         * Parse a workflowDate.
         * @param workflowDate an instance of a workflowDate string.
         * @return the date object containing parsed workflow date.
         */
        private Date parseDate(final String workflowDate)
        {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date retVal = null;

            try
            {
                retVal = df.parse(workflowDate);
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return retVal;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not create a date"? What happens? Any error, exception?

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: In date parsing, `Y` stands for the *week year*. If your problem is related to an undesired output, you can try with `y` instead.

Comment: Unparseable date exception for the above string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` format instead of `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

- y - Year
- M - Month in year
- d - Day in month

Comment: I still get unparseable date for the string "2012-02-20'T'01:01:01"

Comment: `2012-02-20T01:01:01` this is parse-able with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html , beware of the Locale used.